# Using Google Play Services 7.x with Android 6

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-6.0-marshmallow

We upgraded to Google Play Services 8.1 the moment it was out, but now we're considering using a third party library which still has a 7.8 dependency: it hasn't made the required upgrade [mentioned here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/3mehbb/breaking_changes_in_google_play_services_81/).

Reading over the [announcement for Google Play Services 8.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/09/google-play-services-81-get-ready-for.html) there is a mention that

> If your app is using Google Play services SDK versions prior to 8.1, you must update to use this new version to ensure your app is fully compatible with Android 6.0. This will enable you to manage the permission flows appropriately for your app and avoid any potential connection issues.

Potential connection issues sounds like GCM might stop working, but I haven't found any documentation saying what would actually happen if an Android 6 device tried to use Google Play Services 7.x. Has anyone else run into this? Are there any connection issues that I should be concerned about?

Comment: Nothing found for now. If you found, you can report the issue here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list